# Are there any free react date pickers offering a single week view?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I'm looking for a react date picker to use in an application needing to toggle between a single week and single month view.  Are there any free libraries that support these views?

I've found FullCalendar and Mobiscroll but they're both behind paywalls.

Looking around I haven't found anything else.  Will I have to roll my own?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the single week view date picker? I have here my question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80209/react-date-picker-with-week-view

Answer (score 0):

I am confuse, I cannot get what are you trying with saying single week and single month but I used `react-date-picker` (it is free) you can examine it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker) if you like it you can install by 
`npm i react-date-picker` command.I used it as following:

```
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

class Example extends Component{
 state = {
    publishDate: null
 };
 render(){
   return (
      ...
      <DatePicker
          locale="tr"
          onChange={publishDate => this.setState({publishDate})}
          value={this.state.publishDate}
      />
   )
 }
}
```

Comment: I think he ask kind of like this: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80209/react-date-picker-with-week-view